# Trouble connecting to an MSSQL server using ASP.NET 5, Docker, and Ubuntu

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ubuntu, docker

I thought it would be a fun project to play around with an ASP.NET 5 site, in a Docker container, on a Ubuntu server. I've got a simple MVC site running and now I'd like to return data from an MSSQL server but when I run the container, it stops immediately.

The guide I used to build my docker image can be found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/01/14/running-asp-net-5-applications-in-linux-containers-with-docker.aspx

Are there logs that I can view to tell me why my docker image stopped working?

Is it possible to connect to an MSSQL server using ASP.NET 5 within a Docker container on a Linux server?

My Web.Config is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=<mssql_server_fqdn>; Initial Catalog=<db_name>; User ID=<username>; Password=<password>" />
    </connectionStrings>

    <system.web>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

My Model is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace TestMvc.Models
{
    public class Car
    {
        public string Make { get; set; }
    }

    public class DefaultConnection : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to find an error message for us to be able to help you. There could be any number of problems.

Comment: I'd love to and that's why I also asked where the logs may be so that I could provide additional info.

Comment: the command `docker logs your_container`  should show a few things, check the doc http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#logs and you can always enter your container with `docker exec your_container` https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#exec and then debug like you would do in any server., also have a look at the events `docker events`, see the doc https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#events